# Why Spyder 5.0.0 Application Launch Error when launching from user defined environments?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder

I upgraded Spyder to 5.0.0 for all the environments. It launches without error when I launch it from base environment but produces Application Launch Error when I try to launch it from other environments. the error is as follows -

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\KB\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())

File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\KB\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 214, in main
mainwindow.main(options, args)

File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\KB\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 2293, in main
mainwindow = create_window(app, splash, options, args)

File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\KB\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 2146, in create_window
main.setup()

File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\KB\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 882, in setup
plugin_instance = plugin_class(self, configuration=CONF)

File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\KB\lib\site-packages\spyder\api\plugins.py", line 1425, in __init__
widget.set_icon(self.get_icon())

File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\KB\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\profiler\plugin.py", line 70, in get_icon
return self.create_icon('profiler')

File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\KB\lib\site-packages\spyder\api\plugins.py", line 1136, in create_icon
return ima.icon(name)

File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\KB\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\icon_manager.py", line 380, in icon
return qta.icon(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\KB\lib\site-packages\qtawesome\__init__.py", line 146, in icon
return _instance().icon(*names, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\KB\lib\site-packages\qtawesome\iconic_font.py", line 305, in icon
names[i]))

File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\KB\lib\site-packages\qtawesome\iconic_font.py", line 353, in _parse_options
prefix, chars = self._get_prefix_chars(names)

File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\KB\lib\site-packages\qtawesome\iconic_font.py", line 384, in _get_prefix_chars
raise Exception(error)

Exception: Invalid icon name "timer-outline" in font "mdi"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To fix this problem you need to install the **1.0.2** version of the QtAwesome package in your environment.

You can do that by opening the Anaconda Prompt and running the following commands:

```
conda activate KB
conda install qtawesome=1.0.2
```

*Note*: There won't be a need to do this with Spyder 5.0.1, released on April 16th and soon to be part of Anaconda.

Comment: you misspelled qtawesome in your shell command, and SO won't let me edit your post!

Comment: Thanks for noticing it. It's fixed now.